# ReactJS auto audio play working only once, need it to be workable when render is called?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need help in audio play, I'm using this in render that plays sound only once when I change enter something in text field same line executed from render but audio is not playing again. I need this sound play because of sound notification to the user. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<audio className="hidden" controls autoPlay>
      <source src="src/images/note.mp3" />
</audio>
```

Component

```
{ flag === 'online'
                                            ?
  <div>{  onlineUnread === '' ? <div></div>
   :<span>{(onlineUnread.users[0] === userId+".id" || onlineUnread.users[1] === userId+".id") ? '' :<div>
    { (yunread-zunread)+xunread <= 0 ? '' :
      <div>
         <audio className="hidden" controls autoPlay>
           <source src="src/images/note.mp3" />
         </audio>
        {(yunread-zunread)+xunread}
      </div>

     }</div>}</span>

     }</div>
      :
    <span>{xunread <= 0
        ?'':
       <div>
    <audio className="hidden" controls autoPlay>
   <source src="src/images/note.mp3" />
       </audio>
   {xunread}
     </div>}
  </span>
}
```

Comment: Where's your react component?

Comment: @JosanIracheta I have added compnent code, in component these values are changed ```{(yunread-zunread)+xunread}``` and audio is also with this but that is not playing after one play.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another approach via `ref` and use `Audio` API to play the sound.

For example:

```
<audio ref={(audio) => { this.audio = audio }} src="src/images/note.mp3" />
```

And then just call `this.audio.play();` when you need it.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play